# Excel 2013 header and footer is dropping the ampersand and bracket when automated

Tags: c#, excel, header, automation, footer

I have a program that generates reports in Excel 2013.  Code snippet looks something like this:

```
Worksheet sheet = Excel.Workbooks.Add();
string[] footer = new string[] { @"&[Tab]", ProgramName, @"&[Date]" };

sheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = footer[0];
sheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = footer[1];
sheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = footer[2];
```

When I close and reopen the workbook it looks like:

> **Tab] ------------------------- PROGRAM ------------------------- Date]**

*Grrr, insert image is not working and I can't have multiple adjacent white space (just imagine it without the hyphens)*

*Important:* If I immediately try to print the worksheet, the document looks as shown above.  When I simply click in the footer area to edit the footer, it immediately realizes that the value is `&[Date]`.  When the editor leaves focus, the footer correctly displays `4/7/2016`.

So my question is **why is this happening?**  Why/how is Excel getting confused?  Has anyone seen this behavior or *anything* similar?

Just before I posted, I thought it might be because my Excel application is invisible, but no.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure about your language, but in VBA the code would be, for date, `"&D"`.  Using `"&[Date]"` results in similar problems to what you write

Comment: Well, that would line up with my symptoms.  As I think it's only interpreting the first letter after the **&**.  I'll try it... Huzzah, success!  Please repost this as an answer so I can give you due credit.  Also, *wtf* where did this come from?  Do you have any references?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the [reference here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225426(v=office.12).aspx).  Still, *wtf*

Comment: *wtf* is correct as the header in the Excel GUI would display `&[date]`, When I examined the header with VBA, I could see it only contained `&D` as per the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your language, but in VBA the code would be, for date, "&D". Using "&[Date]" results in similar problems to what you write –